# How to properly set up a webmail server

Tags: email

I'm in the middle of a site build and the site requires people to send mail type messages back and forward between users (not like IM, more like the eBay mail system).

I could build this from scratch, but I assume there is a better way of doing it and there is likely something out there that is much more scalable than just storing messages in the database.

I have looked at [Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) but this requires IMAP.

This is where my knowledge gap is...

Is something like Roundcube really what I need?

If so what sort of service am I looking for to do the IMAP? Is this something that most web hosts provide (a personal IMAP server) or is there something like an Amazon cloud based solution to this?

Am I looking for something different that I don't know the name of? Is there already a whole bunch of open source solutions that do what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there are better options for handling internal messaging (but I am not aware of any particular ones). In answer to some of your points:

For IMAP, you just need an email server that supports IMAP.
You could buy your own mail server, or you could make arrangements with an ISP that provides IMAP mailboxes.

Theoretically you would just need to tell Roundcube how to open the IMAP mail accounts (just like you'd tell an email client how to open them. I'm not familiar with Roundcube, but presumably their documentation explains how to do that.

If your mail server is hosted in a different location to Roundcube, you might need to configure access restrictions in the mail server and/or firewall settings if it's hosted on your own network. Basically you just need to make sure Roundcube can pick up the mails.

Of course, this is designed to be a full webmail solution, so I'm not sure if you will be able to cut it down to your own requirement to just contact internal users.

Answer (score 0):

A great solution to this is found at [Expanding.Pro](http://www.expanding.pro)

Super awesome incredible webmail AJAX, shared calendars and contacts, you can set up a server using and control it easily with natural language...really a unique server...totally awesome...has messaging XMPP, video conferencing JINGLE, voice VOIP chat, screen sharing, file transfers, file sharing and more included too.

the difference between this and most other webmail is that this webmail works in the background (written in C) and the entire system drives synchronization of information....

open source operating system.

installation, configuration, and management panel (separate and proprietary...very affordable though)